# how can I detect arrow keys in java?

Tags: java, key, keylistener

I know how to implement a key listener; that's not the problem.

```
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyChar() == KEY_LEFT) {
        cTDirection = LEFT;
    }
    if (event.getKeyChar() == 40) {
        cTDirection = DOWN;
    }
    if (event.getKeyChar() == 39) {
        cTDirection = RIGHT;
    }
    if (event.getKeyChar() == 38) {
        cTDirection = UP;
    }
}
```

What do I put where the `LEFT_KEY` / 40 / 39 / 38? When I created a keylistener and type in the keys, I believe I got 37 - 40. I don't know what to put there to listen for just the arrow keys.

Comment: this should have "AWT" in at list tag, or in the title.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would recommend using:

```
if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
...
}
```

repeating with `VK_DOWN, VK_LEFT, VK_RIGHT`.

There are seperate codes for the numeric keypad: `VK_KP_UP, VK_KP_DOWN, VK_KP_LEFT, VK_KP_RIGHT` if you need them.

See [KeyEvent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) for all of the codes.

Comment: I want just the regular arrow keys... that does not affect my arrow keys!

Comment: Those are the codes for 'regular arrow keys'.  If you are still having problems, I suggest that you post more of your code because you have a problem somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

`KeyEvent.VK_LEFT`, `KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT`, etc.

Also, you should use `getKeyCode`, not `getKeyChar`. `getKeyChar` is for keys that actually correspond to characters (letters, numbers, spaces, etc.).

Comment: I want just the regular arrow keys... that does not affect my arrow keys!

Comment: @user - Yes it **does** affect the arrow keys.

Comment: @user516664 that is the code for the "regular" arrow keys. Maybe you want the numeric keypad arrows instead, in which case use `VK_KP_LEFT`, etc. If that still doesn't work then tell us what `getKeyCode` is returning for your "regular arrow keys".

Comment: I actually did see an example that worked with VK_LEFT and all working, but it wasn't for me - it was returning 37 thought 40 in the order LEFT TOP RIGHT DOWN

Comment: @user516664: Uh... VK_LEFT=37, VK_UP=38, VK_RIGHT=39, VK_DOWN=40. See the table here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_LEFT

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
if ( e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
     //Do something
}
```

The other keys are:

KeyEvent.VK_UP

KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT

KeyEvent.VK_DOWN

Comment: I want just the regular arrow keys... that does not affect my arrow keys!

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did to make it work:

```
public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e) {
        int c = e.getKeyCode ();
        if (c==KeyEvent.VK_UP) {                
            b.y--;   
        } else if(c==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {                
            b.y++;   
        } else if(c==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {                
            b.x--;   
        } else if(c==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {                
            b.x++;   
        }
        System.out.println (b.x);
        b.repaint ();
    }
```

For me it isn't working if I put it in KeyPressed but works fine if I put it in KeyTyped.

Comment: Please don't use some random mark down which you have seen elsewhere. Use the buttons presented in the edit box's toolbar and read up, how to format your code and text, starting with the FAQ. Thank you, and welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`getKeyCode()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyCode%28%29) method and compare the returned value agains `KeyEvent.VK_LEFT`, `KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT`, `KeyEvent.VK_UP` and `KeyEvent.VK_DOWN` constants.

Comment: I want just the regular arrow keys... that does not affect my arrow keys!

Answer (score 0):

first declare init method

```
public void init(){

this.addKeyListener(new keyb());}
```

then use inner class which implements  KeyListner

```
class keyb implements KeyListener{

    public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e){
    if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        y-=50;

    }else if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        y+=50;
    }else if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){            
        x+=50;
    }else if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        x-=50;
    }

    repaint();

    }
    public void keyReleased (KeyEvent e){}
    public void keyTyped (KeyEvent e){}
    }
```

you can also use adapter instead of writing Keyreleased & keyTyped .... as you know

Answer (score -1):

btw in KeyAdapter -> keyTyped getCharCode() didn't work
You should try keyPressed or keyReleased